# Close Opportunity Flow Button Not Showing Up

Tags: opportunity, permissions, profile

I have a flow and an action button affiliated with it.  The flow walks the user through editing a couple fields on Opportunity then closes the Opportunity with the right status.  I've made an action button that initiates the flow visible to users in the Opportunity Layout.

The action button seems to be only showing up for Admins, not for people with the Standard User profile.  I've made sure the Standard Users have Opportunity CRUD permissions and transfer permissions, and that their layout is set correctly, but the button is still not showing up for them.  I've also updated the Opportunity Sharing Settings.

Anything else I should check?

Comment: do they also have Run Flows permission? or defined as a Flow User in their User record?

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flows require explicit permissions to be runnable; and for quick actions associated to flows, if the user doesn't have permission, the action doesn't appear

Flow permissions can be granted in many ways:

- On the User - `Flow User`
- On the Profile - `Run Flows`
- Via a permission set - `Run Flows`
- Flow-specific - `Flows | Security | Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets`

There's a [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-testing-and-distribution/enable-user-access) that goes over this

Answer (score 1):

These are solutions I tried for the flow button issue. Hope this will help.

1. Enable the 'Run Flow' permission in the Profile/Permission set.
2. Check whether the Flow is activated or not.
3. If flow using any Apex class components, Give the permission in the Profile / Permission set level.
4. Finally, check if the Lightning page layout has any rendering conditions for the button.

**#HappyCodings**